# If birthday than photo else no birthdays

Tags: php, mysql

I got it where it shows a photo when its same day as someone's birthdays
But I don't know I get a message there saying when there are no birthdays.
Normally I work with an if and else code but I don't know what to put in the if.

```
<?php
$select = mysql_query("SELECT foto FROM `users` WHERE MONTH(gebdatum) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(gebdatum) = DAY(NOW())");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select))
    if(???????????){
       ?><?php echo $row['foto']; ?>" border="0" style="border:1px #000000     solid"><?php 
    }else{ ?>
       No birthdays
      <?php 
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: **Please**, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799), and `mysql_*` functions have been officially removed in PHP 7. Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either `PDO` or `mysqli_*`. If you can't decide, [this article will help to choose your best option](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: What is `DAY(gebdatum)` and `MONTH(gebdatum)`?

Comment: There is no reason for the various `<?php` and  `?>` throughout your code, it's all PHP, you only need the very first `<?php` and the very last `?>`.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton holy code. I just noticed that thanks to you, i've sweet palms and chills down my spine now.

Comment: If you want to do this for _all_ users, then you need to take the condition out of your query and do the check in PHP instead (that what be what you put in the `if`).  If you just want to see if _anyone_ has a birthday, fetch all rows instead of one-by-one, and then check if the result is empty.  But it's not really clear which of those you want to do.

Comment: @xoxel Sorry, I'm not following what you mean with your comment, I don't understand.

Comment: I'd write a function wrapper around your database call, so you can test this more easily, as it's possible you won't have any birthdays on a particular day.   Change the SQL to return results for a specified day of the year.

Comment: Those poor leap year babies. :-(

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton i was just shocked by the `<?php` & `?>` everywhere. Like, where did he learnt to write php this way ??

Comment: @xoxel Gotcha. I'm not sure where people are learning that, but I've actually seen it quite a bit lately.

Answer (score 2):

One option to consider would be adding a loop counter variable.

Initialize the counter variable to zero before the while loop.

Then increment the counter variable by 1 each time through the loop.

Then after the loop, test the counter variable. If it's zero, then we didn't enter the loop.

This isn't necessarily the best way to do it, but it demonstrates a pattern that we should be familiar with:

```
# initialize loop counter
$i = 0;

while( ... ) {
   # increment loop counter
   $i++;
   ...
}

# test loop counter
if( $i == 0 ) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should not be using the `mysql_*` library; [This is deprecated and insecure](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799).

I would actually suggest using [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), as in my opinion it is much more flexible than the [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) alternative.

### Native PDO

This is how you connect to a database with PDO:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
        echo "Connected successfully"; 
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Now that you are connected, you have a new variable called `$conn`, which is called your database handle.

Now, for the query:

```
<?php
    $results = $conn->query("SELECT foto FROM `users` WHERE MONTH(gebdatum) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(gebdatum) = DAY(NOW())")->fetchAll();
    if(!empty($results)) { //if results is empty, there are no results, so no birthdays.
        foreach($results as $result) {
            echo "{$result['foto']} border='0' style='border:1px #000000 solid'>'";
        }
    } else {
        echo 'No Birthdays';
    }
?>
```

So the `if` statement above will fail if there are no results, so the `foreach` will never run. In `PDO`, you use foreach instead of a while loop usually.

### GrumpyPDO

If you used the class I made [called GrumpyPDO](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/GrumpyPDO/blob/master/grumpypdo.php), this is a tiny bit easier because you don't have to worry about the conenction part of the database, and it's easier to return all the results from your query:

```
<?php
    include "grumpypdo.php";
    $db = new GrumpyPDO("localhost", "username", "password", "database");

    $db->all("SELECT foto FROM `users` WHERE MONTH(gebdatum) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(gebdatum) = DAY(NOW())");
    if(!empty($results)) { //if results is empty, there are no results, so no birthdays.
        foreach($results as $result) {
            echo "{$result['foto']} border='0' style='border:1px #000000 solid'>'";
        }
    } else {
        echo 'No Birthdays';
    }
?>
```

*Disclaimer: I am the author of GrumpyPDO.*

Answer (score -6):

Try this

```
<?php
$select = mysqli_query("SELECT foto FROM `users` WHERE MONTH(gebdatum) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(gebdatum) = DAY(NOW())");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select))
if(!empty($row)){

<?php echo $row['foto']; ?>" border="0" style="border:1px #000000 solid">     
 }else{ 
No birthdays
<?php } ?>
```

Also, please do not use mysql as from PHP 5.6, we use mysqli and now, PHP v7 is there. And, why are you writing

Comment: It won't go into the `while` if there are no rows.

Comment: This code is not functional. You are still calling the `mysql_` libray, and your open and close tags for PHP are also incorrect and will not work. Not to mention OP is using `mysql_`, so they likely do not know anything about `mysqli_`, and it may be useful to provide a link to documentation on how to set up a connection using that interface if you aren't going to show them how to do it with the interface they are currently using. Also, you're if statement is in the wrong place.

Comment: A swing... and a miss.